# how to put whitespace in long Serial println() input

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, c++

I have this long, Serial.println() that is in quotes, on multiple lines.
Arduino IDE warns: "Missing terminating character".
I am certain there is a way to break the lines up, while having the entire text enclosed in quotes, but I don't remember how.

```
Serial.println("
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\" xmlns:cc=\"http://creativecommons.org/ns#\" xmlns:rdf=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#\" 
    xmlns:svg=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:sodipodi=\"http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd\" 
   id=\"svg8\" version=\"1.1\" viewBox=\"0 0 227.35277 156.29323\"
   height=\"6.1532764in\"
   width=\"8.9508963in\"
   sodipodi:docname=\"etchasketchborder.svg\">
    <defs
     id=\"defs2\" />
  <path
     style=\"fill:#ff0000;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:1.32300019;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1\"
     d=\"m 12.000819,0.66145838 c -6.2819637,0 -11.33936062,5.05739692 -11.33936062,11.33936062 V 144.29249 c 0,6.28197 5.05739692,11.33936 11.33936062,11.33936 H 215.35224 c 6.28197,0 11.33885,-5.05739 11.33885,-11.33936 V 12.000819 c 0,-6.2819637 -5.05688,-11.33936062 -11.33885,-11.33936062 z M 18.932696,12.696383 H 205.5854 c 5.02557,0 9.07128,4.04571 9.07128,9.071282 v 77.03923 c 0,5.025575 -4.04571,9.071285 -9.07128,9.071285 H 18.932696 c -5.025572,0 -9.0712819,-4.04571 -9.0712819,-9.071285 v -77.03923 c 0,-5.025572 4.0457099,-9.071282 9.0712819,-9.071282 z\"
    />
  <ellipse
     style=\"fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:1.32300007;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1\"
     cx=\"21.16666\"
     cy=\"130.59085\"
     rx=\"10.583334\"
     ry=\"9.0714283\" />
  <ellipse
     style=\"fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:1.32300007;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1\"
     cx=\"200.62982\"
     cy=\"131.57361\"
     rx=\"10.583334\"
     ry=\"9.0714283\" />
      </svg>
");
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135841/c-multiline-string-literal

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I figured it out.
you cant do this:

```
Serial.println("foo
                                bar");
```

but you can do this:

```
Serial.println("Foo"
                "Bar");
```

So then in bash I write a little command, to take my svg files, and escape the quotes that exist in the file, then another line to add quotes at the start and end of every newline. then I can just copy paste my svg images into the println() function.

```
$ sed -i 's/"/\\"/g' input.svg
```

and

```
$ xargs -I{lin} echo \"{lin}\" <input.svg
```

respectively.

Comment: Note that "foo" "bar" (on separate lines) results in "foobar" not "foo\nbar" as the layout would suggest.

Comment: sure, I was just looking to break it up visually. I think the svg doesnt care about newlines, and if it does, ill just add a \n into my bash script.

Comment: SVG doesn't care (It's just XML after all) - but just something to keep at the back of your mind in case you use the same trick for something that does care (or for other users that read this answer and don't realise that little caveat).